# Why is my email address field not displaying to the right of my radio buttons like I'd like it to?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

It did before, but I changed something and now it won't. I would share code, but I don't know what's exactly relevant. It's all available via the inspector of course.

[Live page](http://web.cs.dal.ca/~selig/serverside/assignment1/)

Comment: unchange what ever you did

Answer (score 1):

The div with id `gender` has a width that is too small for all of the radio buttons and labels to be on one line. Remove the width css property from `#gender`.

Answer (score 1):

@Doug Smith remove `width: 95px;` from #email